# Triggering github workflow on a push, when a certain file is changed

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Here's an example workflow

```
name: Example

on:
    pull_request:
        branches: [main, dev]
        types: [opened, reopened]
    push:
        paths:
            - './.github/workflows/always.yml'
jobs:
    print_dir:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: print
        run: |
          ls -la .
```

This workflow doesn't seem to be triggered when the always.yml file is changed. However, if I change the `paths`to `paths_ignore`, a change to any file not in under `paths_ignore` will trigger the workflow...

Comment: Did you try using `.github/workflows/always.yml` instead of `./.github/workflows/always.yml` in your `paths` configurations?

Comment: Great, I'll add it as official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related to the `path` you informed in your configurations.

You need to use:

```
on:
    push:
        paths:
            - '.github/workflows/always.yml'
```

With `'.github/workflows/always.yml'` instead of `'./.github/workflows/always.yml'`